# Select top 5 from each month using value counts on a DateTimeIndex with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a `pandas DataFrame` with a `DatetimeIndex`. I want to `resample` by `month` and get the `top 5` for each `month` in the `DataFrame` from a particular `column` however using `nlargest(5)` gives me the top 5 of the whole DataFrame instead of by month:

Here is a `snippet` of my code:

```
df.resample("M").productID.value_counts().nlargest(5)
```

This gives me the top 5 for the whole DataFrame, I need to have top 5 for each month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `value_counts` sorting by default is possible use `head` instead `nlargest`:

```
df.resample("M").productID.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(5))
```